# How Do I Access Elements in Specific Sections of A Table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how would I access the hair with Javascript (as in Black)? I tried using normal accessing from within other elements gradually through defining variables accessing the table and tr it was in, but it still didn't work. Please respond if you have an answer. Thx

```
<table id="customers" class="customers">
  <tr class="parent" data-toggle="toggle">
    <th id="rank" style="text-align: center;">Number</th>
    <th id="name" style="text-align: center;">Name</th>
    <th id="name" style="text-align: center;"></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody class="content">
    <div class="one">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="name">Object A</td>
        <td class="down">
          <button onclick="toggleText()" type="button" class="collapsible" id="1">
            +
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
    <tr class="panel" id="one-a" colspan="3">
      <div class="panel">
        <td class="expand">
          <div class="hair">
            Black
          </div>
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It may have something to do with the table being a table and not being able to fetch certain values like normal code.

Comment: have you tried using getelementsbyclassname and checking the innerhtml?

Comment: Start by validating your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var hairColor = document.getElementsByClassName("hair")[0].innerHTML;
```

it will return an array of elements , your array will be of length 1 (because you only have one tag with the specified class, "hair" in this case) so the value you need is of index 0.
[How to use JavaScript to get elements by class name?](https://flexiple.com/javascript-get-element-by-class/)